# Turn a single sed command into a reusable Textmate command

Tags: text, editor, sed, textmate

I have 7 lines of text:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

Now I want to add characters to the end of each line, to end up with:

```
a,
b,
c,
d,
e,
f,
g,
```

I found that I can use the "sed" command and run my selection through sed using "Filter through command" in Textmate

```
sed 's/$/,/'
```

Now, one question remains: how do I turn this into a Textmate command that takes input in some sort of way (so it knows what text to append)?

(My tries in doing this have proven unsuccessful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pop this into a command within the Text bundle, it'll append whatever is in the clipboard to the end of all lines that have been selected:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(pbpaste|wc -l) -eq 0 ]]
    then r=`pbpaste`
    sed 's/$/'$r'/'
    else sed 's/$/,/'
fi
```

It's currently limited to appending one line's worth of text, if the clipboard contains more than one line it will default to a comma at the end of the selected lines.

**Edit:**

To take this a little further, here's a version that provides a dialog box which prompts for the input of the string that will be appended to each line in the selection:

```
#!/bin/bash
r=$(CocoaDialog inputbox --title "String to be appended to EOL" \
   --informative-text "Enter string:" \
   --button1 "Okay" --button2 "Cancel")

[[ $(head -n1 <<<"$r") == "2" ]] && exit_discard

r=$(tail -n1 <<<"$r")

sed "s/$/$r/"
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Text** menu there is already a command "***Edit each line in selection***" exactly do this. It will put cursor on first line and what you type there repeated on each line.

Comment: I know; but it doesn’t seem to be able to prepend. If I place my cursor at the beginning of the line, hit the shortcut, then it jumps to the end.

I could use column selections but then I'm using the mouse again, which isn't speedy enough.

Comment: column selection doesn't need mouse. use page up + shift and press option when done.

I don't know about sed. but in textmate you can write bundle command very easily that replace selection with sed processed text if you know sed/ruby/regex+ruby etc.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new command in the bundle editor

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 's/$/,/'
```

On the input dropdown select **Selected text** or **Nothing**

On the output select **Replace existing text**

I just tested it and it works fine. 
You can also choose a keyboard shortcut to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to avoid the command route and simply use the Find/Replace dialog simply do as follows:

- highlight/select the lines you'd like to append to
- open the Find dialog
- check 'Regular Expressions'
- in the 'Find' field, add `'$'` (to indicate the end of the line)
- in the 'Replace' field, add `','` (what you want appended)
- hold `Option`, this will change "Replace All" to "In Selection"

This technique can be applied in a number of other useful ways. For example, changing `'$'` to `'^'` if you want to prefix each line.